# Getting nil value when passing value to api

Tags: ios, swift

Things i did :

1. I have one url api which will display some data in my table view.
   2.And i fetch the particular value called "_id" from my url and i just pass that value to one custom class object.
2. Then i am passing that class object value to one of my another api calling url.In there i getting the value as nil.

Here is the code that ia m populating the data to my table view.And i am taking the particular value from api "_id" And i am storing that value to one custom class object :

```
// Showing favourites
    func populateFavourites()
    {
        let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("access_token") as! String

        let headers = ["x-access-token": token]

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "some url")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error)
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    {

                        print("Success Got Json Data")

                        let success = json["success"] as? Int

                        if(success == 1)
                        {
                            let jsonData = json["data"] as! NSArray

                            if(jsonData.count>0)
                            {



                                for items in jsonData
                                {
                                    let BObj = items as! NSDictionary

                                    let BusinessDetails = BObj.valueForKey("business_id") as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

                                    self.FavBusinessValues.append(Businessdata(json:BusinessDetails))
                                                                      print(items)

                                     let FavId = BObj.valueForKey("_id") as! String


                                    self.FavDelete?.FavIds = FavId

                                    print(FavId)




                                }

                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                self.CreateNoDataLabel()
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            let message = json["message"] as? String

                            print("Fav Message ",message)

                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error: ", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                            // add an action (button)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                            // show the alert
                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()

    }
```

In my above code i am taking the particular value "_id" and i am passing to my custom objet class :

```
 let FavId = BObj.valueForKey("_id") as! String
 self.FavDelete?.FavIds = FavId
 print(FavId)
```

This `print(FavId)` is printing the correct value.Here is my cutom class object that store that value of "_id" :

```
import Foundation
class Favdelete
{
        var FavIds : String?


    init(json:String)
    {

        self.FavIds = json as? String

    }
}
```

Then i am passing the "_id" objet value `FavIds` to my one of my api calling.That code is under below :

```
 func apidelete () {



           let Favouriteid = FavDelete?.FavIds
                           print(Favouriteid)

              let userToken = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("access_token") as! String;
        print(userToken)


                        let headers = [
                            "x-access-token": userToken,
                            "cache-control": "no-cache",
                            "postman-token": "81fbd1fc-c333-3ceb-272a-a9ecffb2dad2",
                            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                        ]




        let FBI = "favourite_id="+Favouriteid!


        let postData = NSMutableData(data: FBI.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

                        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "some url")!,
                                                          cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    {

                        print("Success Got Json Data");

                        let success = json["success"] as? Int;

                        var message:String = "";

                        if(success == 1)
                        {
                            message = json["message"] as! String;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            message = json["message"] as! String;
                        }

                        print(message);

                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message from server", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }
                })

            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()




    }
```

When i try to print this :

```
let Favouriteid = FavDelete?.FavIds
  print(Favouriteid)
```

I ma getting crash and it says nil printing in my console.

Can any one please help me out.!!

Updated :

Under my first function method.That is when i get the particular value and store that value to my custom object .I just print it.I am getting nil there too.

The line is :

```
let FavId = BObj.valueForKey("_id") as! String
 self.FavDelete?.FavIds = FavId
print(self.FavDelete?.FavIds)
```

Its printing nil

Updated :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have a custom class you need to initialize it to use its method. Without proper initialization you cannot set its properties. 
So in the ViewController, declare the object for that class at the top.
`var FavbDelete : Favdelete?`
At this point, your FavDelete is nil.

Then you get the "_id" from `populateFavourites()` method. You may be calling it from viewDidLoad() method. There you get FabId as
`let FavId = BObj.valueForKey("_id") as! String`
But now you cannot directly store it into `FabDelete` Object. because it has not been initialized. Although Xcode doesn't throw any error when you do that, But the resulting value will be nil. So now you initialize that object using the initializer you built in custom class.

`self.FavDelete = Favdelete(json: FavId)`

Now the `FavDelete` object is initialized , and when you call `apidelete`() method after this step, you can access the value of id by using

```
let someVar = self.FavDelete?.FavIds
```

Since, all of this work is being done in background using `NSURLSession`,ensure that you are not calling `apidelete` before the `FabDelete` Object is initialized.

Comment: i tried but i am getting error that ` Cannot call value of non-function type 'Favdelete?'`

Comment: In your update code, can you print after this line 
`let FavId = BObj.valueForKey("_id") as! String` to see if the Fav Id is not nil?

Comment: When i print  `let FavId = BObj.valueForKey("_id") as! String` now i am getting the correct id

Comment: i am getting this error " Cannot call value of non-function type 'Favdelete?'"

Comment: Have you setup variable for FabDelete? 
`var FavDelete:Favdelete?`

Comment: no.Becuse i created one custom class for that.See my post

Comment: should i need to create that `var FavDelete:Favdelete? `

Comment: Instead of that i am having `  var FavDelete = Favdelete?()`

Comment: i already initialize the value like this in my custom class : ` var FavIds : String?`  `self.FavIds = json["_id"] as? String;`

Comment: But still i am not able to access the value

Comment: @mark can you provide me link to your code of both ViewController and your custom class so that i can look what is wrong in it?

Comment: please download from here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/to6tipe0d9o1def/Archive%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: please see my comment i have attached the drop box link to download

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsb6ax5xm70lsm4/Archive%202%20-%20edit.rar?dl=0
Here i have updated some code. Can you try this once?

Comment: sure...Wil try and let you know

Comment: update that code with var FavDelete:Favdelete!

your class name is "Favdelete" and your variable name is FavDelete" . "D" is what was wrong

Comment: this this print function error "  ` Value of type 'FavViewController' has no member 'favDelete'`

Comment: Sorry once again. Please change that `favDelete` to `FavDelete` in that print method too.

Comment: great worked. But one question. I need to reload my table view.Because this viewcontroller is for delete the data from table view.Now after delete i need to reload my table view.So, where i can assign that ??

Comment: First off all remove the data which you want to delete from your arrays. Then call tableView.reloadData() method. You can do it from anywhere. I don't quite understand what your apidelete() method does. But if your apidelete method() make a call to your server, delete the data from there, and then you have to update the tableview.. After receiving response, delete the data from your array and then call tableView.reloadData() method.

Don't forget to mark the answer accepted ;)

Comment: thats what i am asking where should i add that table view reload

Comment: I add that line in all line under `apidelete method()` As you said its correct to call the api and to delete

Comment: Yes, its correct. Add it inside dispatch_async when success == 1

Comment: And one more question i have.In my console i am getting my value with name optional.Does it will cause any problem in app??.And also i tried adding that table view all over code inside that `apidelete method()` but still not able to reload

Comment: ??.What should i do here??

Comment: Yes i can understant that `FavBusinessValues` is supply the data to display in my table view.But if you see my whole class method what i have send you in drop box.In that, i am having one bar button item and if i press one check box will display with table view cell.So if i select any check box that cell will delete.So in this case where i have to write the table view reload line ??

Comment: That `apidelete method()` method is to delete the table view cell for selected data.So after the success ==1 i will reload the table view.But it doesn't work

Comment: When the user clicks on that checkbox,find that data element in array,delete that data element from array and reload the tableview there.

Comment: Actually i can understand what you are saying.But my `apidelete method()` is to delete the data in table view.So only i reload the table view after the sucess == 1.But why should i reload the table view when user click check box. can you please tell me exact place with compare of my code that you have (drop box code).I am new to ios.Not able to understant where i have to reload the table view

Comment: There are lots of code and i don't know which methods does what. So I am unable to say you with reference to your code. But you can put it anywhere, Just create one method which removes data from array and in the same method at the end put tableview.reloadData().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112100/discussion-between-idocode-and-mark).

Comment: okay.But if i create one method then how can i remove the data...Because already no data in my table view when i perform delete api calling

Comment: its working but it deleting all the data in my table view.Why this happening ??